# How do I find which tables have foreign keys on my table?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is there a query I can do to find which tables have foreign keys on a given table?  Our DBA does not believe in (or understand?) "ON DELETE CASCADE", so I when I delete something from a table, I want to make sure I delete all the dependent stuff first.

(Note, I don't need to find the tables programmatically, I can do that in SQL*Plus.)

Comment: Sounds more "does not believe". ON DELETE CASCADE does the same as looking into constraints and delete reference records.

Comment: However, ON DELETE CASCADE is notoriously slow; if it's a large job, it's usually better to delete all of the children first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT dc.constraint_name, dc.constraint_type, dc.owner, dc.table_name
FROM dba_cons_columns dcc 
JOIN dba_constraints dc ON (dcc.constraint_name = dc.r_constraint_name and dc.owner = dcc.owner)
WHERE dcc.owner = 'OWNER_NAME' and dcc.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: I had to change the second line to `FROM dba_cons_columns dcc JOIN dba_constraints dc ON (dcc.constraint_name = dc.r_constraint_name and dc.owner = dcc.owner)` because multiple owners have the same constraint names.

Answer (score 1):

Check `all_constraints` and `all_cons_columns` dictionaries.

Comment: I don't see a column in those dictionaries that tell you which table the foreign key is for, so if I `select * from all_constraints where table_name = 'CLIENT'` and it shows me all the indexes and constraints on `CLIENT`, but I can't find a query that shows me which tables have a foreign key on CLIENT.

Comment: Oh, but if I `select * from all_constraints where r_constraint_name = 'PK__CLIENT'` it does what I want.  Mostly.